# Eclipse switch to new Version Problems with Projectstructure

Tags: eclipse, directory-structure

with my Win10 machine and Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Developers version 2020-12 I can import existing projects without any problems - the folder structure is as before (version Kepler).
Now I tried to upgrade to Eclipse 2021-12.

This resulted in the following problem with the folder structure:
Eclipse does not create the Java Resources Folder.

[Eclipse 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdNNz.jpg)
[Eclipse 2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9xAb.jpg)

I have tried the IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers version.
Not being familiar with Eclipse, I have no idea how to get Eclipse to create the Java Resources folder and put the src and Libraries folders in that folder.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It was not a real folder, just something used to collect all of your Java Build Path content in the Project Explorer view, and has no impact on whether everything else is present.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you explain me, why does Eclipse2020 show it in this structure and Eclipse 2021 not?

Comment: That content provider was removed.

Comment: In this case a Java library or a plugin is missing?

Comment: Neither. That feature was removed.

Comment: Thanks to your hints the servlet is starting now - thank you very much!

Comment: Was it not starting before?

Comment: No, there were problems with the BuiltPath and I thought that they arose because of the faulty project structure. Thanks to your hints I fixed them and now I can start the servlet and connect to it.

Comment: One last problem still exists:
I start the server (Apache Tomcat V7) externally everything is fine. However, when I start it from Eclipse, special characters (è and é) are displayed incorrectly (question mark in a diamond).
The problem does not occur with the old Eclipse (I have compared properties).
I don't know where Eclipse intervenes in the coding. When receiving data from the main application, the servlet already doesn't decode it correctly (I use the same Java version on both machines).
Do you have an idea about this or should I ask a new question?
Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: Probably a different question, but clarifying where it's being displayed. Usually it's the font not having the character, sometimes it's the encoding's character set not representing it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify where the characters are not displayed correctly.
Our application sends the telegrams to the servlet and already there in the logfile I see that the characters do not arrive correctly. Whereas with an external startup they are written correctly in the logfile. 
So it must be (I think at least) the new version of Eclipse and its settings - but I can't find which...